# How do I use camlp4 in an OCaml program to parse another OCaml program into an AST?

Tags: parsing, ocaml, abstract-syntax-tree, camlp4

I'm currently trying to translate OCaml programs (with a fairly standard/limited grammar) into Racket, and I'm trying to see if there is a way to do the parsing to intermediate representation using camlp4. I tried to build a lexer and parser using ocamlyacc and ocamllex but considering how large the grammar can be, it became quite complicated. So, I searched around and found camlp4 to have some of this already built-in, but I can't seem to look up how to get the AST of some OCaml code using it. Any documentation/examples/ideas? Also, if you have any suggestions on how to do this better, that'd be great as well! Thanks.

Comment: Probably you should look at camlp5 and base your project on theirs scheme extension: http://camlp5.gforge.inria.fr/doc/htmlc/scheme.html

Answer (score 4):

Just use compiler-libs, which is distributed with the compiler. You can use the ocaml parser itself directly that way.

Here is an [example of code that reads a .ml file](https://github.com/ocsigen/eliomlang/blob/519a812d34f786e444ef1181bf9ed8fb437feb66/bin/ppx_tester.ml#L2-L12). The documentation for the parser is quite decent. You will obtain, after parsing, a [Parsetree](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/parsing/parsetree.mli).

Comment: Kind of a dumb question, but how do I go about loading the Parse module in? Using Windows is making things like ocamlfind and opam impossible to install.

Comment: It is a rather unrelated question which you should ask separately.  In short, in Windows there are several ways to use ocamlfind and opam too (ex. http://protz.github.io/ocaml-installer/).  However, the cost is still high: you will face tons of glitches.  To me, the best is to install a virtual Linux environment.

Comment: Re: tons of glitches; that's exactly what I'm facing now. I'll see if I can work on a Linux environment somehow. Thanks.